# How to design a precision (small) axle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

For a mechanical design, I would need a small/light axle, having high precision (as less loose as possible and reduced drag). With precision, there is not a very strict definition, however, I target ~0.2º of radial rotation (axial movement is not that an issue).

The length of the axle is around 24mm, on which I would attach a few elements (~50g).

---

The first idea is to use a bearing on each side of the axle, but I am not sure what is the good practice for attaching the bearing.

Following is my current sketch:

[image]

The closest example of what I am doing is the axle in the actuator of a Hard-Disk, however, the bearing there is internally tapped for fixation. Most of the bearing I found on the market are not tapped. My feeling is that tapping the bearing is not a good idea.

[image]

---

My question is:

**What are the commonly use pieces, practices, terms and fixations for this type of problem?**

I understand is a quite broad question, but either I miss terminologies and in any case I did not found answers online. Also, I do not need a deep answer, but some indications of where to look further.

Others possible tags: axle, matched-set

Comment: Do you mean "axle" ?   Further,  what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What is wrong, in your opinion, with tapping the bearing? It is tapped early in its manufacturing process before being assembled and even, before hardening.

Comment: The inner metal sheet of the bearing I seen seem to thin for tapping it. Even if feasible without breaking the bearing, the result seem too weak to me. My concern is about tapping an existing bearing, not about manufacturing a tapped bearing.

Comment: The inner and outer surfaces of bearings are hardened, as I mentioned, you will break a tap trying to tap them. I pointed out the manufacturing process so you would understand that the tapping operation is completed before the bearing inner race is hardened.

Comment: Here is a sketch of design, for clarity. @SolarMike: I understand, and that exactly bring this question: if bearing are usually not tapped and is not practical to tap them, how to fix the bearing to the axle? is that even a good idea?

Comment: You can thread the axle and use a nut and locking washer, you can put a groove in the axle and use a circlip - just two possibilities.

Comment: Take a floppy drive or a CD ROM drive apart; the bar upon which the head slides is very precise, hard, and should be what you need. As for affixing the bearings, the usual approach is a minuscule amount of super-glue.

Comment: Press fits are quite common, so is Loctite on a less precise fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axle type rod is available under different names on-line. Try searching for "8mm linear shaft", "linear rail shaft", "ground polished shaft" just to start.

Bearings that fit snug don't require much of a fastener to keep them from walking off of the shaft. You could machine a hole through the end, or a groove around the end, and use an R-clip or c-clip snapped onto the end. It would probably be overkill, but you could drill and tap a hole straight into the center of each end for a screw and washer.